# Unable to run PyCharm apps after reinstalling Python 3 with Homebrew

Tags: python, terminal

I deleted Python 3.7 from my computer and reinstalled it with Homebrew. Now, my virtual environment is broken after I `brew cleanup`.

Here is the error:

```
/Users/thomastseng/PycharmProjects/firstapp/venv/bin/python "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py" 53280 53281 /Users/thomastseng/PycharmProjects/Games/app.py
dyld: Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python
  Referenced from: /Users/thomastseng/PycharmProjects/firstapp/venv/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
Couldn't connect to console process.
```

Is there any way I could fix the error? I can't use `li` or `virtualenv`. Thank you!

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: I ended up resetting my whole Mac and reinstalling Python.